# Is it possible to parse/traverse react code in Python?

Tags: python, reactjs

I know I can use node.js and `@babel/parse` and `@babel/traverse` to get an Abstract Syntax Tree of a react code file, and run code on its different nodes.

However, we're creating a static code analyzer in Python and we want to parse/analyze react code and some other programming languages codes.

Is it possible to get AST of react in Python and traverse it in Python code?